Error while creating index template for opensearch using terraform
I am trying to create opensearch templates using terraform and getting below error.

*Error: HEAD healthcheck failed: This is usually due to network or permission issues. The underlying error isn't accessible, please debug by disabling healthchecks.
with opensearch_index_template.template-product-base-input-test,
on main.tf line 127, in resource "opensearch_index_template" "template-product-base-input-test":
127: resource "opensearch_index_template" "template-product-base-input-test"     > {*

We have configured SAML authentication for our opensearch domain/cluster. Here is our provider.tf file for the same.
provider "opensearch" {
 url                 = aws_elasticsearch_domain.opensearch.endpoint
 aws_region          = var.region
 aws_access_key      = ""
 aws_secret_key      = ""
 healthcheck         = false
}

Could you please help to fix the error?
The resource block is defined below.
resource "opensearch_index_template" "template-product-base-input-test" {
  name = "template-product-base-input-test"
  body = <<EOF
  {
  "index_patterns": ["product-base-input-test*"],
  "template": {
   "settings": {
    "number_of_shards": 5,
    "number_of_replicas": 1,
    "index.mapping.coerce": false
   }
  }
}
EOF
}

Also,our OpenSearch domain uses an internal user database so we tried with username and password as well as below.
provider "opensearch" {
  url                 = aws_elasticsearch_domain.opensearch.endpoint
  aws_region          = var.region
  username = "XXXX"
  password = "XXXX"
  sign_aws_requests = false
  healthcheck         = false
}


And where is the offending line from the error? Can you add that resource to the question?

@GunjitSidher please edit your question and add the details you pasted as a comment

Where is the cluster running from, i.e., is it from private subnets or public subnets?

Cluster is running from private subnet. @MarkoE

Can you access it when you are not using the provider?

We are able to access the dashboards and can create templates manually inside it. But it's throwing error when we are trying to create using terraform script.

So you can access the UI from your machine, but not with the provider?

We created the opensearch using terraform itself and can access that. But now when we are trying to create the index templates inside opensearch using terraform, we are getting error.

I think the error says exactly what the problem is: This is usually due to network or permission issues.

Did you try adding "https" to your URL configuration on the provider?
something like:
url                 = "https://${aws_elasticsearch_domain.opensearch.endpoint}"
This fixed it for me.

this also worked for me, as well as putting proxy = ""
